# GDI Image::Save returns Win32Error

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I am using GDI Image::Save Method to save the images to the file in my
Application. 
 I am getting Win32Error (7) status error in few instances
with Vista 64 bit. It is working fine with vista 32 bits. 
and also this problem is coming randomly .

Can you please suggest how to solve the problem

Thanks in advance

Regards
Subbi Reddy

Comment: What is the return value from `GetLastEror()` when the Win32Error is returned?

Answer (score 0):

*One* possible case when this is happening is when the image's underlying stream has been closed:

```
using ( var fs = new FileStream( filename, FileMode.Open ) ) 
    bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream( fs );
```

If you now try to save bmp this error can occur. Your problem may, of course, be something completely different.

You could, however, try to save a copy of your image instead of saving the image directly, like so:

```
using ( var tempBitmap = new Bimap( oldBitmap ) ) 
    tempBitmap.Save( ...... );
```